# How to import .py file from another directory in animationnodes2.1?

Tags: python, animation-nodes

I am writing a custom node in animation nodes2.1,and i wanted to import .py file from another directory as a module,for example,i have two directories:

```
../nodes/my_nodes/test.py

../nodes/bvh_tree/construct.py
```

i wanted to import construct.py to my test.py,i tried this code:

```
from ..bvh_tree import construct
from construct import ConstructBVHTreeNode
```

but failed,the consoul gave me ***"no moule named construct"***,i was confused about the error,how to fix this problem? i had tried the way on the topic [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22955684/how-to-import-py-file-from-another-directory/22956038),but can not work still,anyone has an idea,Thanks in advanced!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a general Python question which isn't unique to Blender.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Th import statement should be:

```
from .. bvh_tree.construct import ConstructBVHTreeNode
```

Because the `from import` takes the form `from module import something`.

Comment: Thank you very much! i have leaned a lot by you!